# display executing name of the current running script

Tags: racket

I have tried a few methods, one of them being:

```
 (define (program) (find-system-path 'pref-file))
```

I have read from the documentation (after attempting the above code) and have noticed it is not what i'd need to use, obviously :) Any ideas?

Would also like to save this information to a variables. VBS example:

script = WScript.ScriptFullName

Comment: This will never display anything, it will only return a result for a call to "program".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket

(display "Program name: ")
(displayln (find-system-path 'run-file))
```

Output (if saved as "test.rkt" and run with the command `racket test.rkt`):

```
Program name: test.rkt
```

From the `racket` console REPL, `(find-system-path 'run-file)` will return `#<path:racket>`. I didn't try it in DrRacket.